# JMF - big files (2GB) - no 'movi' chunk error

Tags: java, size, jmf, avi

I have a question. Anybody try to open big AVI files (>= 2GB) in JMF player? This is an AVI file where two streams located: video and audio. Video stream has no any compression, fccHandler = 'DIB ' (like uncompressed BMP files). Sound data are not compressed too. So, file is big. For 2-3 minutes it has size 2 Gb.

When I try to open and play it in JMF I see error:
"

```
Failed to configure: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@edbca8
  Bad header in the media: No movi chunk

Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@edbca8
javax.media.CannotRealizeException
    at javax.media.Manager.blockingCall(Manager.java:2005)
    at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:528)
    ...
```

".

This file correctly opens with any video player: Media Player, QuickTime, VLC, etc.

No problem if size approximately 400-500 Mb, JMP opens it with no issues.

Anybody try to open big AVI files (>= 2GB) in JMF player? And may be this issue is completely known. And may be solution exists.

Thanks!

P.S. I can't use any compression and other approaches to minimize size of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what happen. Microsoft declared 2GB limitation for "Video for Windows" format, which was implemented in JMF.

I wrote it here to help someone solve the same problem.

Workarounds: use OpenDML AVI, use another format, make partial AVI-files (<= 2 GB each part).

Thanks!!!